# How to create fluent methods with 2 Generic Types?

Tags: c#

I have the following classes (omitted properties for sake of simplicity):

```
public class Person {
  public Address Address { get; set; }
  public Hobby Hobby { get; set; }
}

public class Address {
  public Country Country { get; set; }
}

public class Country { }

public class Hobby { }
```

And I created an IncludeMapper to be used, if possible, as follows:

```
IncludeMapper<Person> m = IncludeMapper
  .For<Person>()
  .Add(person => person.Address).And(address => address.Country)
  .Add(person => person.Hobby);
```

**Add** will take the base type, e.g, Person.
**And** will take the type used in the previous Add or And.

```
public class IncludeMapper {
  public static IncludeMapper<T> For<T>() {
    return new IncludeMapper<T>();
  }
}

public class IncludeMapper<T> {

  public IncludeMapper<T> Add<K>(String expression, Expression<Func<T, K>> property) {
    return this;
  }

  public IncludeMapper<K> And<K>(String expression, Expression<Func<T, K>> property) {
    return this;
  }
}
```

This won't work ... I think I need to return  on the methods and I might need an extra class because the For is only for T?

Could someone help me out with this?

Comment: In your example, `And` returns an address mapper, not a person mapper, so the second `Add` call isn't going to work anyway. Perhaps `Add` needs an overload that takes an extra argument so you can pass in a child mapper, instead of that `And` method? `Add(p => p.Address, IncludeMapper.For<Address>().Add(a => a.Country)`, or maybe just `Add(p => p.Address, a => a.Country)`.

Comment: Yes, I know ... But wouldn't this possible by returning always IncludeMapper<T, K> ... So T would always be the base type so I could use Add after an And and K would be so And could use the previous type ... Not sure how to make this compatible with For<T> that is why I think I might need an extra class here ... Not sure.